# Correct Usage of Derivative and Partial Derivative Symbols in Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In the following second-order partial differential equation for $f$ with $x$ and $t$ as independent variables, $a$ and $b$ as constants, and $g$ as a known function with $t$ as the only independent variable

$$a \frac{ \partial^2 f}{ \partial x^2 } + b \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial t } + \frac{ dg }{ dt } = 0$$

is the mathematically correct notation for the third term on the left-hand side $\frac{ dg }{ dt }$ as above, or $\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial t }$?
Some may say that $\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial t }$ is correct because it is a term in a partial differential equation, but since $g$ is a one variable function with $t$ only, I think $\frac{ dg }{ dt }$ is correct according to the original usage of the derivative and partial derivative symbol.
The original usage of the partial derivative symbol is to express the rate of change of a multivariable function of two or more variables when all variables except the variable to be used in the  differentiation are fixed, and the notation $\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial t }$ implies that $g$ is not a one variable function, which would be somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: Does not really matter. The meaning is clear either way.

Comment: Partial derivatives are for functions of several variables. $g$ is a function of a single variable. There's no issue of "correctness."

Comment: Thank Prof Deane. As you say, it is a trivial problem since it makes no difference which notation is used for solving partial differential equations. However, I would like to be as accurate as possible in the formulas I use in the design manuals I create for my work, given the influence that design manuals have on almost everyone involved in the industry who adopts the design methods described in them. The first version of the question specified the independent variables for f and g, but the manual does not, so I have revised the question.

Comment: I think your notation is correct, but really you need to make it clear that this is a given function of $t$ only. From the viewpoint of the PDE, it’s just some known function of $t$.

Comment: Thank Sean. In the first version, the independent variables of $f$ and $g$ were specified, but as per Dr. Dean's answer, they are not mentioned in the manual, so I have modified the question so that they are not specified in this question as well. As you say, since $g$ is a univariate function and $\frac { \partial (･) } { \partial t }$ is used for a multivariate function, we should originally use $\frac { dg } { dt }$.

Comment: Thank Prof. Shifrin. As you say, it would be preferable to specify the independent variables so that the reader can more accurately grasp the contents of the equation. Actually, the first version of this question clearly stated the independent variable $t$ for $g$, but as I indicated in my response to Prof. Deane, I plan to include the partial differential equation for this question in a certain manual on design and have aligned the notation there.